# Controlling UIScrollView from from child UIVIewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

So I'm trying to get the Snapchat style of UIViewControllers to be able to swipe between them. I have the swipe part working fine, but I'd also like to be able to move between view controllers by pressing a button, and this is where I'm falling down.

I have a parent or container view controller with a UIScrollView in it, then I add the UIViewControllers to it and the scroll view as follows:

```
self.addChildViewController(ViewControllerA)
self.scrollView!.addSubview(ViewControllerA.view)
ViewControllerA.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

And so on for each one.

Now the problem is that the UIScrollView is housed in the Container view, so when I press a button in ViewControllerA, I want to call a function in the Container view to move the scroll view.

I was going to use a delegate, but I think I'm right in saying I need to write a separate delegate for each child view which seems like a bit of a code smell to me.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me like the parent/container view controller would be the delegate. Each of your children would have a delegate property, conforming to the same protocol, and each one would point to the same parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a way.

I created another View Controller and put my protocol on there. Then instead of making my child view controllers subclasses of UIViewController, they are now subclasses of my new SliderViewController and can call the delegate function it houses

Answer (score 0):

Your parentViewController should be the delegate of your childViewControllers.

in your child view controller :

```
protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate {
func shouldScrollToPage1()
}

class ChildViewController {

weak var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate? = nil

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.shouldScrollToPage1()
    }
}
```

In the ParentViewController :

```
extension ParentViewcontroller:  ChildViewControllerDelegate{

func shouldScrollToPage1()
//Do you sroll here
}

}
```

When you instantiate your ChildViewController in the parent just add that :

```
viewControllerA.delegate = self
```

Comment: But this way would I not have to make the parent view controller the delegate of each one of my child view controllers?

Comment: Yes you would. I've seen that you found your solution, that's good ;)